# java.io.StreamCorruptedException : invalid stream header:

Tags: java, jdbc

I get this exception when I run `executeQuery(sqlStr)` (JDBC) and my select selects a Blob column that was written by `java.sql.PreparedStatement.setBytes( someByteArray )`

Do I need to specify the header somehow?

Thank you

Comment: Please provide the full exception

Comment: This usually suggest a low level protocol error such as the client jar being too old for the server you are connecting to.

Comment: ok @PeterLawrey, you can post it as an answer, it solved my problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This usually suggest a low level protocol error such as the client jar being too old for the server you are connecting to.